# What does "difference" refer to when Eron says “I'm not around enough people to know the difference”?

Tags: upgrade-2018

In *Upgrade* (2018), Eron visits Grey, who lost use of his hands:

> Eron: You're someone who liked to get things done with their hands. Now you can't. I'm sorry, was that inappropriate? I'm not around enough people to know the **difference**.

What does "difference" refer to?

Comment: The difference between saying something socially appropriate and not

Comment: As I think had been commented to your other questions, you can accept a check answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: @FuzzyBoots other questions are **unanswered**.

Comment: My apologies. I thought one of them had. Sadly, I dunt have a copy of the movie to rewatch, so I can't help that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Valorum stated, Eron has difficulty understanding how social interactions work, so he doesn't know the difference between an appropriate and an inappropriate thing to say. He blames it on social isolation, but it's also implied that he's on the [autism spectrum](https://www.nimh.nih.gov/health/topics/autism-spectrum-disorders-asd/index.shtml), which is often associated with the tech field.